# How do I make *tree* list hidden files as well?

Tags: command-line, tree

I'm using this package called `tree` to list sub directories and files in a given directory. It works fine except it doesn't list hidden files.

When I run `tree` in a folder it returns

```
├── Zodiac (2007)
│   └── Zodiac (2007).mkv
├── Zombieland (2009) H
│   └── Zombieland (2009) H.mkv
└── Zootopia (2016)
    ├── Zootopia (2016).mkv
    └── Zootopia (2016).srt
```

But it should've returned hidden files named `.folder.png` in each one of these folders.

Can I make it happen?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use `tree -a`

```
$ man tree
-a     All files are printed.  By default tree does not print hidden files 
(those beginning with a dot `.').  
In no event does tree print the file system constructs 
`.' (current directory) and `..' (previous directory).
```

Comment: I looked at the manual. In my case I wanted to list hidden directories but no files. The `-a` flag says _files_.

Answer (score 4):

Also `gvfs` stuff are installed in many systems, you can use them too:

```
gvfs-tree -h
```

Answer (score 1):

gvfs-tree has been deprecated in Debian and ubuntu systems use

`gio tree -h`

Comment: Auch, interesting. When was it deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Using tree -a can often be too verbose. Add -L  to limit depth if you just need a good overview of the top-level directory structure including hidden files.

```
tree -a -L 2
```